# Display bug in "Similar questions" dropdown when Asking a question (Firefox)

Tags: bug, asking-questions, firefox, similar-questions

Text gets overlaid on top of itself and unreadable when scrolling the "Similar questions" dropdown when Asking a question.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Start typing the question title. "Similar questions" list gets populated.
2. Scroll the "Similar questions" list - OK
3. Go back to the question title and refine it.
4. Scroll the "Similar questions" list - text is overlaid when scrolled!?

Tested Firefox v72.0.2 and v73.0

Doesn't seem to be a problem in Chrome/Opera.

Close and reopen the dropdown does resolve the issue.

[image: Similar questions list when asking a question]